# How to check that one of the radio button is select in View?

Tags: django

It should be very simple but I could not found how I can check that one of the radio button was selected

```
class ViewSettingsForm (forms.Form):

  CHOICES=[('select1','select 1',),
         ('select2','select 2'),  ('select3','select 3')]

    like = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    name = forms.ChoiceField()


def view_settings (request) :
     owner = request.user
     if request.POST:
          # ??? How to check that something was selected
     else :
         form = ViewSettingsForm ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
    print request.POST.get('like')
except:
    print "nothing was selected"
```